# Topological space that contains only ﬁnitely open sets.

Tags: general-topology

Prove or disprove

If $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\tau$ contains only ﬁnitely many open sets, then $X$ is a ﬁnite set.

Comment: Yes it is correct, the trivial topology on the set $X$ containing only two open sets ($\emptyset ,X$) has always only two open sets and $X$ can be any set (finite or infinite).

Comment: Yes.  X doesn't have to be R.  It can be any set.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct. If you want a no trivial example you can take $X$ a infinite set and $A \subset X$. Then the set $\tau = \{ \emptyset, A , X \}$ is a finite topology for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes: the trivial topology always contains at most two elements.